# Which 'delta' to use from those returned by 'orddom' package in R with argument 'paired = TRUE'?

Tags: r, nonparametric, effect-size

I have used the `orddom` package in R with the argument `paired = TRUE` to calculate the Cliff’s delta for paired groups, and a 4-column-matrix containing 29 rows with values was returned. The ordinal statistics can be retrieved from the first three columns. But comparing 2 paired groups I need only one delta result. Which of the three do I need? I guess I need one from the first two columns (the second?), but I am not sure which.

I searched the R documentation and on the Internet, but I did not find an answer to my question.

Comment: Please feel free to email me (Package Author)!
Jens Rogmann, University of Hamburg, Germany